# RStudio for loop in columns

Tags: r, sorting, for-loop, addition

How can I make a for loop in RStudio that can add the first column to odd columns like 1st column to 3rd and then to 5th. and I want to sort the even column so sort 2nd column, 4th column and so on
my cods are as following

```
se = "!^GATTACA"
com_seq<-str_replace_all(x, c("A"="1", "C"="2", "G"="3", "T"="4", "\\^"="5", "\\!"="6"))
sp<-strsplit(com_seq, "")[[1]]
com_seq2<-data.frame(sp)
com_seq2
```

please help

Comment: Hi, please have a look on my new codes. I convert the letters in numbers so I can sort the way I want. now am have an issue creating the for loop that can add the first column on the left side of the sorted next column and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive function, `make`, that accepts an initial vector `x` and an odd number of `sort/paste` operations.

```r
make <- function(x0, n) {
  f <- function(x, m) {
    if(m <= n) {
      y <- paste(x[[ncol(x)]], x0)
      y <- data.frame(y, sort(y))
      names(y) <- paste("column", m:(m + 1L), sep = "_")
      out <- cbind(x, y)
      Recall(out, m + 2L)
    } else return(x)
  }
  x <- data.frame(x0, sort(x0))
  names(x) <- paste("column", 1:2, sep = "_")
  f(x, 3L)
}

first_column<- c("^","G","A","T","T","A","C","A")
make(first_column, 3)
#>   column_1 column_2 column_3 column_4
#> 1        ^        ^      ^ ^      ^ ^
#> 2        G        A      A G      A A
#> 3        A        A      A A      A G
#> 4        T        A      A T      A T
#> 5        T        C      C T      C T
#> 6        A        G      G A      G A
#> 7        C        T      T C      T A
#> 8        A        T      T A      T C
make(first_column, 5)
#>   column_1 column_2 column_3 column_4 column_5 column_6
#> 1        ^        ^      ^ ^      ^ ^    ^ ^ ^    ^ ^ ^
#> 2        G        A      A G      A A    A A G    A A G
#> 3        A        A      A A      A G    A G A    A G A
#> 4        T        A      A T      A T    A T T    A T T
#> 5        T        C      C T      C T    C T T    C T T
#> 6        A        G      G A      G A    G A A    G A A
#> 7        C        T      T C      T A    T A C    T A C
#> 8        A        T      T A      T C    T C A    T C A
make(first_column, 7)
#>   column_1 column_2 column_3 column_4 column_5 column_6 column_7 column_8
#> 1        ^        ^      ^ ^      ^ ^    ^ ^ ^    ^ ^ ^  ^ ^ ^ ^  ^ ^ ^ ^
#> 2        G        A      A G      A A    A A G    A A G  A A G G  A A G G
#> 3        A        A      A A      A G    A G A    A G A  A G A A  A G A A
#> 4        T        A      A T      A T    A T T    A T T  A T T T  A T T T
#> 5        T        C      C T      C T    C T T    C T T  C T T T  C T T T
#> 6        A        G      G A      G A    G A A    G A A  G A A A  G A A A
#> 7        C        T      T C      T A    T A C    T A C  T A C C  T A C C
#> 8        A        T      T A      T C    T C A    T C A  T C A A  T C A A
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thanks for your answer but I need column1 to be printed in front of of the other columns

Comment: please how can I get this code using a for loop instead if loop @Rui Barradas